# How do you insert images into table using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to insert images to "choicesDiv". How can I do so without editing HTML & CSS? Table code below:

```
<table id="choices">
  <tr>
    <td><div class="choicesDiv" value="1"></div></td>
    <td><div class="choicesDiv" value="2"></div></td>
    <td><div class="choicesDiv" value="3"></div></td>
    <td><div class="choicesDiv" value="4"></div></td>
    <td><div class="choicesDiv" value="5"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="choicesDiv" value="6"></div></td>
    <td><div class="choicesDiv" value="7"></div></td>
    <td><div class="choicesDiv" value="8"></div></td>
    <td><div class="choicesDiv" value="9"></div></td>
    <td><div class="choicesDiv" value="10"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/append, plain JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Comment: Try this, https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/jOPrgqO

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to post that code as well.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/r7foy58g/

Answer (score -2):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".choicesDiv").append("<img src='your-image-src'/>" )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="choices">
  <tr>
    <td><div class="choicesDiv" value="1"></div></td>
    <td><div class="choicesDiv" value="2"></div></td>
    <td><div class="choicesDiv" value="3"></div></td>
    <td><div class="choicesDiv" value="4"></div></td>
    <td><div class="choicesDiv" value="5"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="choicesDiv" value="6"></div></td>
    <td><div class="choicesDiv" value="7"></div></td>
    <td><div class="choicesDiv" value="8"></div></td>
    <td><div class="choicesDiv" value="9"></div></td>
    <td><div class="choicesDiv" value="10"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That works! Any idea how I can implement the "random" codes? I would like to have 10 different images in the choicesDiv & the images change it place whenever the page refresh,

Comment: You can change with each function , Put your images in each function and implement in shared code.(if you satisfy with my answer my vote me)